# Unable to go back after refreshing from a Modal screen using React Navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-native-web

Let's suppose I have a TabNavigator. In a screen, I'm able to navigate to a modal screen (full screen modal => it's placed outside the TabNavigator stack) and go back but, if I refresh the browser in the modal screen (F5), I'm unable to go back. The go back button disappears.

I can even reproduce it with the Expo init typescript tabbed default project.

Video describing the problem: https://recordit.co/4PULNdWRPT

Code: https://github.com/MADSENSE/Madsense.ReactNative.Sample/tree/master

Does anywone knows how to fix this / any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you expect while navigating a web app. Whoever, you can force the icon to show and navigate to wherever you want manually.

example:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="..."
  component={...}
  options={navigation => ({
    headerLeft: props => <IconComponent onPress={navigation.navigate("...")} />,
  })}
/>
```

Also, you have to navigate to a screen by its name `navigation.navigate("...")` because you can't tell from where the user went to your screen.

Comment: Please remove the untested tag if this code works for you (or tell me to remove it)

Comment: So, with your solution I can make it work. I have improved it a little bit by checking `navigation.canGoBack()` first, so in case I'm able to goBack, I navigate back. Otherwise, I do the navigation. But, since it's placed inside another stack, I need to navigate to a nested screen https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators